# In which event should one set dynamic control properties?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, page-lifecycle

[This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx) article states that `Page_PreInit` should be used to

> create or re-create dynamic controls.

**For example:**

```
Button button = new Button();
somePanel.Controls.Add(button);
```

**Good. I understand.**

**However**, it also says:

> If the request is a postback, the values of the controls have not yet
>   been restored from view state. If you set a control property at this
>   stage, its value might be overwritten in the next event.

**Huh?**

Does this mean that all I should do is create the button, but not set any members of the button?

For example:

```
Button button = new Button() { CommandArgument="arg" };
somePanel.Controls.Add(button);
```

Does this mean that setting `CommandArgument` in this event is incorrect/not recommended/might cause an error/unexpected behavior?

Assuming it is incorrect, this would lead me to think that one would have to do something like this:

```
protected void Page_PreInit(object sender.....)
{
    somePanel.Controls.Add((new Button());
}

protected void Page_Init(object sender.....)
{
    foreach(Button button in somePanel.Controls)
      button.CommandArgument = "arg";
}
```

is this the right way?

**Finally, in which event should one set dynamic control properties?**

Comment: Do what the article states.. have it in the init and then have some If IsPostBack code.. you could do it on pre-render or PreInit as well in my opinion

Comment: @DJKRAZE - I am confused about what the article states, hence the question :).

Answer (score 1):

There is no single answer for that last question as depending on the nature of the property it may or may not make sense to set a value in a specific method.

> If the request is a postback, the values of the controls have not yet
>   been restored from view state. If you set a control property at this
>   stage, its value might be overwritten in the next event.

Might is the keyword here.  If you consider some properties that may change as a form goes through various states then this is where you have to be careful of what may get overwritten as well as the question of whether or not this is a bad thing as it may be that the updated value should persistent and in other cases the original value may be better such as if someone wants to reset the form to its initial state.

My suggestion would be to do some trial and error to see what works as I can remember working with dynamic controls that could be tricky in some me cases to manage properly.